# Why does a class return an instance of itself?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have an abstract class..

```
public abstract class MHandle {
    public MHandle getMHandle(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

I also have another class called House

```
public class House extends MHandle{
    public void methodA(){
    }
}
```

what would be the point of doing something like

```
public void methodA(){
    MHandle mh = getMHandle();
}
```

Comment: Cant understand qustion

Comment: `instance` of an `abstract` class ??  ^_^ OOP break.

Comment: It will return the same instance no matter in which class the method is defined, so it is completely pointless. In every context you could call ```getMHandle()```, you could more easily call ```this``` or use the instance on which you would call it.

Comment: The only difference I can think of is that the reflection methods most likely will return different values!?

Comment: If you would like to return instance of base class(supposing it is not abstract) you should use key word "super".
    
    public void methodA(){
       MHandle mh = super.getMHandle();
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between this:

```
public void methodA(){
   MHandle mh = getMHandle();
   mh.toString();
}
```

and this

```
public void methodA(){
   this.toString();
}
```

and this

```
public void methodA(){
   toString();
}
```

and this

```
public void methodA(){
   this.getMHandle().getMHandle().getMHandle().getMHandle().
      getMHandle().getMHandle().toString();
}
```

This non-difference is true in any context. Internally to the `MHandle` class or its concrete sub-classes (such as `House`), and also to classes that do-or-don't have access to the `MHandle` class. I don't see the point of having `getMHandle()` at all, if all it does is return a self-reference without ***doing anything useful***.

Comment: Mind if we generalize then?

Why would a class, in any situation, return an instance of itself?

Comment: I can't think of any reason for doing that. You *could*, but it's absolutely pointless. If a class has a reference to another, then what's the point of `[a-class-instance-which-I-obviously-already-have-an-instance-of].getInstanceOfThatClass()`  ? You might as well do the equally-pointless `[a-class-instance-which-I-obviously-already-have-an-instance-of].getInstanceOfThatClass().getInstanceOfThatClass().getInstanceOfThatClass().getInstanceOfThatClass().getInstanceOfThatClass().getInstanceOfThatClass().getInstanceOfThatClass().getInstanceOfThatClass()`.  They're equal.

Comment: Anon, a side effect of returning "yourself" is that more code can be written into a single statement. For example, the append method from StringBufffer. `StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); sb.append("a").append("b").append("c");` that works.

Comment: returning an instance of itself is an example for the Builder Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern see the StringBuffer example in the comment before

Comment: Yes, self-returning functions are supposed to *do something useful* and ***then*** return a reference to themselves. The OP's question returns itself without doing anything else.

Comment: @aliteralmind, the OP's code is also only an example. Absurd-Mind's answer is more useful to the OP in my opinion.

Comment: So there would never be a point for doing something like

`public MHandle getMHandle(){
return new MHandle();
}`

unless im dealing with something like what munyul mentioned?

am I correct?

Comment: @Anon: Returning a *new* object is different than returning a reference to itself--the *current* instance. There may be some use-cases for that. @munyul: The OP's question (and example-code) is about a function returning a reference to itself, without doing anything else. That's the question I answered. Agreed that the builder and `StringBuilder` information is valuable.

Comment: Thank you very much. My question would have made more sense  if I had the method that was returning an instance of itself `getMHandle();`  as `static`.

Thank you all for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

One aspect could be covariance: This method can be overridden to return a more specific type:

```
public abstract class MyMoreSpecificHandle extends MHandle {
    public MyMoreSpecificHandle getMHandle(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

There is also an application of something like this known as "The getThis() trick". It is related to the covariance aspect, and explained here in detail: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206

Answer (score 0):

This will return the House instance,Since it extends MHandle.